# Inject form value in a service with angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass the input values of a form (mdf) to another component using a service.This is my service:

**sharedData.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {
    eventData: any=[];

    constructor() {}
    setEventData(data: any)
    {
      this.eventData.push(data);
    }

    getEventData()
    {
      return this.eventData;
    }
}
```

In the first component, when I'm clicking a button I want to pass the form value to the service:

**formData.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="eventForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="eventForm.valid && add(eventForm.value)">
<fieldset>
<input  name="title" formControlName="title" type="text">
......
<a [routerLink]="['/preview']" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="preview(eventForm.value)">Preview</a>
......
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**formData.component.ts**

```
preview(eventData: any)
  {
    this.sharedData.setEventData(eventData);
  }
```

**preview.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventData=this.sharedData.getEventData();

  }
```

but nothing shows up in

**preview.component.html**

```
<b>Event Title: </b> {{eventData.title}}
```

Comment: You have set [routerLink]="['/preview']" and (click) event both. Have you tried **this.router.navigate** inside (click) event instead of [routerLink]

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder yes, I did try that with a button click event too, that is not the problem, gives the same output

Comment: Have you tried to check the **eventData** value?

Comment: eventData is an array. An array doesn't have any title attribute.

Comment: @JBNizet even if I assign it to a model type which has title attribute it doesn't return anything either

Comment: So, what happens if you use `{{ eventData[0].title }}` instead?

Comment: @JBNizet nothing, empty value

Comment: this.sharedData.setEventData(eventData); //  you need to call sharedData method of SharedService. Import SharedService into your component ts file and try.

Comment: @Nutan yes, ofcourse I did that, didn't mention here to keep it short

Comment: Works fine here. Check your console for errors. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a plunkr.

Comment: Forgot the plunkr I created to try reproducing your issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/IRMxf6d2WNxPQUVMuOna?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet after pulling my hair out  I finally understood where the problem is, the problem lies in routing. when routing to new page everything gets refreshed and data gets lost, http://plnkr.co/edit/NpLKAgY3FkzhOK9eBeIb?p=preview this is working but I still need to open the page in a new tab without refreshing

Answer (score 0):

oky.. Try below code. It might help : -                                                                                                             Try adding RxJs for setting and getting data .Example:

```
import { Injectable ,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject }    from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

    private eventDataDetails = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(this.details);
    eventDataDetailsAsObservable = this.eventDataDetails.asObservable();
    eventData: any=[];

    setEventData(data : Object){
        this.eventDataDetails.next(data);
    }

    getEventData(){
        return this.eventDataDetails.getValue();
    }
}
```

In your component : 
import sharedService;

in your constructor of preview component write below lines:-

```
this.sharedDataService.eventDataDetailsAsObservable.subscribe(
            (eventDataResponse: any) => {
                // Your logic here
                this.eventData=this.eventDataResponse;
    });
```

Comment: after pulling my hair out I finally understood where the problem is, the problem lies in routing. when routing to new page everything gets refreshed and data gets lost, plnkr.co/edit/NpLKAgY3FkzhOK9eBeIb?p=preview this is working but I still need to open the page in a new tab without refreshing